# Como copiar dados banco de dados firebird fdb para gdb

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Tenho um banco de dados `firebird` no formato `fdb`,nele tem uma tabela que quero importar para outro banco `firebird` no formato `gbd`.

Como faço esse processo ?

Comment: Você pode salvar um script de insert e rodar no outro bd

Comment: Há muitas formas diferentes. Se você utilizar o IBExpert, por exemplo, há um comando "Export Data into Script". Para rodar o script no banco de destino use o "Script Executive".